# Customizing log destination syslog-ng using macros

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, syslog-ng

I have installed Syslog-ng 3.25, the server is working and I can save data in mongo db without a problem, but I want to customize the destination of data depending on some properties, like source IP, and date, so for every day the server will save logs in a new location.
I defined the destination like this
destination d_pppoedb {

```
 mongodb(
        uri("mongodb://localhost:27017/syslog")
        collection("${HOST}${YEAR}${MONTH}${DAY}")
 persist-name(d_pppoedb)
    
    );

};
```

but it seems the macros are not working, as no new collection has been created in my MongoDB
then I tried with save logs to file using this

```
destination d_file {
        file("/var/log/${YEAR}.${MONTH}.${DAY}/${HOST}.log");
};
```

but it same, no new file has been created, why macros are not working.  when I set the destination as a static value, it is working and save logs without any problem but it does not want to work with macros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mongodb()` destination currently does not support macros in its `collection()` option. You can open a feature request on [GitHub](https://github.com/syslog-ng/syslog-ng/issues/new/choose), if you want to see that in a future release.

Your second example, however, should work as expected. In case `${YEAR}.${MONTH}.${DAY}` directories do not exist, you should add the `create-dirs(yes)` option as well.

Comment: thanks for your reply , so can I define variable outside of colllection and call that variable in the collection ?like create variable with  {$HOST}${YEAR} and then use that variable in mongo collection ?

Comment: There is no easy workaround for multi-collection mongodb(), a mongodb() destination currently can connect to one single collection.